# Can one physical disk provide space for several volume groups?

Tags: linux, lvm

Can one physical disk provide space for several volume groups?

Or one disk can have only one volume group in the Linux LVM?

Can we use one disk in several VG's?

Comment: Short: yes, no, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can provide space for several VGs, e.g. by partitioning the drive and allocating the different partitions to different VGs. I am not sure if there is an advantage, it seems to me less flexible with allocating and moving space from one Logical Volume to anohter than if you have one VG with multiple LVs.

Comment: Yeah, in general, you should have as few VGs as possible in the system, it just makes things easier 3 years down the road when plans change.  Most of the servers that I've built in the last few years have all had a single VG, even though they had a mix of SSD / 10k SAS / 7200 RPM disks, as you can just used "pvmove" to put the LVs on the right disk for the purpose.